# How to convert int array (holding float value in Hex) back into float value in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a automated test program that requires me to generate an int array datastream (which actually holds float data)

To generate that int array, i try to

1. write a floating number into char byte array, and then
2. convert the char byte array into an int array, which later
3. convert back the number from the int array to floating point ( without losing the decimal points).

I was able to do step 1 & 2 without issue, but I can't convert the int array back to floating point using ( float)(*int_ptr).

**My code:**

```
int ibuff[10];

int *int_ptr;

float f=0.1;

char c [sizeof(float)];


memcpy(c, &f, sizeof(float)); //now c is 0x3f800000;  

ibuff[0]=(c[3]<<24 | c[2]<<16 | c[1]<<8 | c[0]);  //ibuff[0] is now also 0x3f800000

int_ptr=&ibuff[0];

printf("%f\n", (float)(*int_ptr)); //this will print out 1065353216.0000, and not 1.0 as I expected
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array of float instead of an array of int?

Comment: Why both c++ and c? Are you aware that they are different languages?

Comment: Are you really looking for a `union { int i; float f; };` where you'll assign to the `int` and read from the `float`?

Comment: I think he is looking for a `union`, but ignoring the strict aliasing issue, his immediate issue is `(float)(*int_ptr)` instead of `*(float*)(int_ptr)`.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben and David. Your suggestion works, now i'm printing out the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direct problem comes from casting the dereferenced integer pointer `int_ptr` to a `float` and then attempting to print that value as a `float`. You are currently attempting:

```
printf("%f\n", (float)(*int_ptr));
```

which as you have found will not work. What you want to do is interpret the *value at the address held by* `int_ptr` as a `float`. To accomplish that, you will need:

```
printf("%f\n", *(float*)(int_ptr));
```

While you can view the address as anything your like, you must make sure you do not run afoul of the *strict-aliasing* rules set forth in the C-standard at rules `6.5 (6)` and `6.5 (7)`. There are limited exceptions specified, but as stated: *"The intent ... is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased."* Technically your cast from `int` to `float` is a violation which is masked by the use of a pointer (arrived at through the intervening use of a character array, which muddies the water a bit further).

Answer (score 0):

In your print statement:

```
(float)(*int_ptr)
```

You are casting an int to a float, ie `(float)(int)(x)` will be the value of `x` as a float instead of an int. What you want is the memory of the location to be interperated as a float, so you need:

```
*(float *)(int_ptr)
```